# Electron 4.0.0 win.setEnabled on mac - doesn’t work

Tags: electron

I'm using Electron 4.0.0 version. macOS Hight Sierra 10.13.3.

While `win.setEnabled(bool)` is working fine on Windows, when running on mac the app gets stuck.

No error is being thrown / printed to console - just stuck (only app manual termination can shut down electron in this case).

Didn’t see anything spacial in Electron api docs and nothing in the web about this kind of issue on mac.
What could be the reason ?
did I miss a limitation regarding supported OSs ?